# svg is playing in reverse and bottom reduce

Tags: css, vue.js, animation, svg

I am confused and i search one day with not success.
I got a project in full Vuejs and i try Svg is easy and a lot of fun but i do not understand why image resize when i playing a animation.

Is my big problem the bottom of svg resize and get smaller i don't know why ?
https://codepen.io/deeluxe/pen/VwvdgrN

```
 <svg class="svg-wave" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1440 932">
  <path class="polymorph" d="M485.168 37.924C264.292 -30.76 69.6908 9.30565 0 37.924V932H1442V105.029C1336.46 77.3975 1129.89 162.266 1019.35 160.785C908.815 159.305 761.264 123.779 485.168 37.924Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="775.269" y1="112.006" x2="722.687" y2="680.065" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop stop-color="#05CDDA"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#034E53"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
```

And if i try a simple Gauge i got this is played reversed !

https://codepen.io/deeluxe/pen/mdeKvYe

```
<svg class="svg-wave" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin  meet" width="240" height="561" viewBox="0 0 240 561" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="polymorph" d="M239.5 0.5H0.5V560.5H239.5V0.5Z" fill="#EC0000"/>
</svg>
anime({
    targets: '.polymorph',
    d: [
      { value: 'M239.5 0H0.5V118.5H239.5V0Z'},
    ],
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: 8000,
    loop: true
  });
```

I take a copy svg with a Figma. If anyone can repair one of two code i maybe understand what is going on :/

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood what you're asking then the problem with the first example is just that the target path isn't quite what you want.

Inside the `d` value there's a section that says `V895`. That draws down to point 895. But your `viewBox` has height 932, so there are 37 pixels left as a gap at the bottom.

Contrast that with your original path which has `V932`, drawing all the way to the bottom.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do or how you ended up in this situation but changing `V895` to `V932` in the target `d` value should prevent the bottom of the blue region from creeping up.

I don't really understand what problem you're describing for the second example. If it's playing in reverse then surely you just need to switch the two paths around?

**Update:**

First, I recommend the MDN guide to SVGs. It is an excellent introduction to drawing basic shapes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial

For your latest example there are some strange things going on with half pixels. By itself there's nothing wrong with using half-pixels but it isn't being consistent between the start path and the end path.

Here's one way you might achieve the desired effect.

First let's draw the initial rectangle. You can use `<rect>` to draw a rectangle but I'll stick to using `<path>` as it's what you've been using.

First I'd move the cursor to the bottom-left of the image. That's `M0 300`. Then I'd draw the horizontal line along the bottom, `H652`. Then up the right-hand side, `V0`. Then along the top, `H0`. Finally, use a `Z` to join it up to the start. Note that with capital letters the co-ordinates are all absolute, not relative. So when I write something like `V0` that means *'move vertically until y is 0'*. You could do something similar using lower-case letters and then the numbers would be relative to the current cursor position.

The finished path is:

```html
<path class="polymorph" d="M0 300H652V0H0Z" fill="black"/>
```

You can insert extra spaces to make it easier to read, `M0 300 H652 V0 H0 Z`.

For the target path it's very similar except we need to change the `V0`. We don't want the black rectangle to extend all the way to the top (the top being 0). In your example you had the rectangle's final height as 44, so I'm going to stick with that. Given we have a `viewBox` height of 300 that means we need `V256`, which is `300 - 44`.

So that gives:

```js
{ value: 'M0 300H652V256H0Z'}
```

To solve these kinds of problems I suggest turning off the animation. Instead just try to draw the target path in your static HTML. Once you've got it drawing the right thing you can move on to trying to animate it.

Comment: Is for a background on a website. For the first is work like i want so thanks a lot, I don't know why the V895 is not stay at 932. 

For the second my problem is after one day of SVG i have a lot of problem on SVG and forum or course on youtube don't help me. So i try understand. 

I complety change, now you can understand :
https://codepen.io/deeluxe/pen/mdeKvYe

Ir the black screen close from bottom to top, but i want is close from top to bottom what i need to do ?

Because on my svg if i reduce top or bottom nothing change is stay like that.Is just for me for understand. Thanks !

Comment: @RaphaelRollet I have updated my answer to address your latest example. In future could you please edit the question to include extra information rather than putting it in the comments? That makes it easier for other people to understand what's going on.

Comment: Yes sur ! Thanks a lot for you'r time it's very clear now !